# Issue With Files Not Opening With Office365

Tags: excel, sharepoint, office365

My company uses a SharePoint site for our department where we share resources and documentation. We currently have a primary Excel sheet linked that contains a massive amount of our day to day info and our most common hurdles and pertains to about 80% of our workflow. This was created before the company switched (recently) to Office365 and the web based applications vs the standalone programs. Now it is not letting anyone open the the sheet because it is still trying to open in the Excel program and not the web app.

We previously used Office '13 and there was never any issue. The link is meant to open the Excel sheet right up in a read only capacity and not save the program because the content is being updated regularly with new information and regulations. With the "upgrade" from the older version of Office to the 365 web based standard version this link no longer opens the file directly, it saves to the PC and then needs to be loaded to the web app from the saved version which completely negates the ability for it to be dynamically updated. Inversely, we could import that into One Drive and update it to the new system and set the link to the view only shareable link but that would take an excessive amount of time to reformat and edit on top of everything else. If that is how we need to do it then that is how we need to do it, but is there anyway to just update the link already in the system so that it can allow the file to be opened in the web app as well as the stand alone for those not upgraded yet or with the advanced version (managers) that still uses the programs and not the web apps?

I expect the file to be able to be opened in Office365 Excel web app read only as opposed to being saved to the local machine and if possible also be opened directly in the standalone Excel program for those using the 365 Advanced version or who have not yet completed the upgrade process that the company is currently rolling out.

Thank you for your time with this.

Comment: I was not sure if this was the right place to ask but I have come to this community many times to look up questions and learn and it seems very knowledgeable and since it is regarding the linking of files in the SharePoint website I thought maybe it would be considered as web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by simply upgrading the whole department and to the Office 365 Advanced version circumventing the entire issue, thank you for your time regardless.